# How to pass an object from callback to errback (twisted)?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I have a callback chain with an errback at the end. If any of the callbacks fail, I need to pass an object to be used on errBack.

**How can I pass an object from callback to the errback?**

The following code exemplifies what I want to do:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import FAILURE
from twisted.internet import defer


class CodMsg(object):
    def __init__(self, code, msg):
        self.code = code
        self.msg = msg

class Resource(object):

    @classmethod
    def checkCondition(cls, result):
        if result == "error":
            cdm = CodMsg(1, 'Error 1')
            raise FAILURE, cdm
        else:
            return "ok"

    @classmethod
    def erBackTst (cls, result):

        ####### How to get the value of cdm here? ########  <<<===
        print 'Error:'
        print result
        return result


d = defer.Deferred()

d.addCallback(Resource.checkCondition)


d.addErrback(Resource.erBackTst)

d.callback("error")

print d.result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can just raise an exception, containing all info you need

For example:

```
from twisted.internet import defer

class MyCustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, code):
        self.code = code
        self.message = msg

def callback(result):
    print result
    raise MyCustomException('Message', 23)

def errback(failure):
    # failure.value is an exception instance that you raised in callback
    print failure.value.message
    print failure.value.code

d = defer.Deferred()
d.addCallback(callback)
d.addErrback(errback)

d.callback("error")
```

Also for better understanding deffereds and async programming you can read this nice twisted tutorial http://krondo.com/an-introduction-to-asynchronous-programming-and-twisted/. 
It uses a little bit outdated twisted version in examples but it is still an exellent source to start learning twisted

Comment: Excelent. Works fine. Thanks @Evgeny Barbashov